# Can option buyers exercise their options after the market has closed on weekdays?

Tags: options

Although the question is in the title, I'm trading AMC options on NYSE, and I'm the seller of a vertical spread.  Can I get assigned after the market has closed on weekdays like today?  I've heard that 1:30 hours after the market has closed on Fridays it can be exercised, but today is a Thursday.  So can I suddenly wake up to know that I'm at a loss?

Comment: You can wake up and be at a loss whether the owner exercises or not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The owner of an American style option (equities) can exercise his contract any time before expiration.  It's my understanding that you have until 5:30 PM EST to do so on expiration day but I have read articles that say 5:00 PM.

Exercise of your option does not create a loss.  Assuming that there isn't a pending dividend,  the ITM short leg is already ITM with no time premium remaining.  You have already incurred the loss.  It's just not realized until assignment occurs.

Comment: well im still not at a loss its just that the contract is reaching closer and closer to the strike price which makes me really nervous

Comment: If the short option is approaching the strike, it might be a good idea to either close the position or roll it down a strike or more.  If it gets ITM, you'll be buying back intrinsic value if you want to close and that will be more costly.

Comment: nearly had an heart attack today, i decided to hold the shares, i was running 38/28 vertical spreads on AMC with the expiration set for today, when i woke up and saw that the options volume was over the top i freaked out, but my broker takes so much comition that its better to risk 900€ than go at a loss when even when the delta on the contract is pretty much gone